# rspec feature spec with javascript enabled throw error "couldn't find with id"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, selenium-webdriver, capybara, poltergeist

I know there has been answers related to this question, but I haven't found the answer for my problem. Consider the following spec:

```
feature "Order Feature", :js do
  let!(:product) { create :product }

  scenario "buy a product" do
    visit product_path(product)
  end
end
```

The above spec will throw error as follows:

```
Couldn't find Product with 'id'=3
```

I have tried the following solution and none helped:

- turning off transactional fixtures
- database cleaner with truncation strategy on example with `:js` enabled ([reference](http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/))
- shared connection with transactional fixtures turned on ([reference](https://gist.github.com/josevalim/470808))

I have used selenium-webdriver and poltergeist, both seem to have the same symptoms, which can be summarized as follows:

***I can see the product being created on the console if I debug the spec, but I could not see any product from the browser.***

I have read several articles that this is related to the capybara is run on the different thread than the spec. But I haven't found anything that helped me resolve this issue.

---

For completeness, I use the following code for shared connection approach:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
end

class ActiveRecord::Base
  mattr_accessor :shared_connection
  @@shared_connection = nil

  def self.connection
    @@shared_connection || retrieve_connection
  end
end

Spring.after_fork do
  # Forces all threads to share the same connection. This works on
  # Capybara because it starts the web server in a thread.
  ActiveRecord::Base.shared_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
end
```

And I use the following for the database cleaner approach:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, :js) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: To diagnose what's happening, I'd start with the shared connection approach and make sure that you're using the same connection in both RSpec and in the controller (e.g. by examining `Product.connection.object_id in both places).

Comment: Checked, using the shared connection approach, the `Product.connection.object_id` is different.